# What is the principle bundle of Oriented Orthonormal Frames $F_{oo}\left(S^{2}\times S^{1}\right)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, principal-bundles

I'm looking for the total space. I know that $F_{oo}\left(S^{n}\right)=SO(n+1)$. I'm guessing that it's not as simple as:

$$F_{oo}\left(S^{2}\times S^{1}\right)=F_{oo}\left(S^{2}\right)\times F_{oo}\left(S^{1}\right)=SO(3)\times SO(2)$$

I would definitely expect it to have more than 4 dimensions. It's a closed space, but not simply connected. From another perspective:

$$S^{2}\times S^{1}=\frac{SU(2)}{U(1)}\times U(1)=\frac{S^{3}}{U(1)}\times U(1)$$

So maybe it's something very similar to $F_{oo}(S^{3})=SO(4)$? Because the products are simple, low dimensional manifolds I thought this would be easy, but honestly I'm not sure where to go from here lol!

Comment: Hint:  $S^2\times S^1$ is parallelizable.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oh gotcha! Totally slipped my mind to consider that! $F_{oo}=S^2\times S^1 \times SO(3) $

Comment: Correct.  If you'd like to post a full answer, please feel free.

Comment: @JasonDeVito just one more thing, I might be confused. $S^3$ is parallelizable, but I'd read $F(S^3)=SO(4)$ rather than $S^3 \times SO(3)$

Comment: Hm, well $S^3\times SO(3)$ and $SO(4)$ are diffeomorphic (but not Lie-isomorphic), so maybe that's what the authors intended?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I'm sure you're right. Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I am interested to know (at the level of imagination) is it really important to talk about Lie-isomorphicity of two diffeomorphic spaces? Also, is it meaningless to talk about deformation (and have Lie group structure during deformation) between two Lie group that are diffeomorphic?

Comment: @C.F.G:  With regards to Lie isomorphism compared with diffeomorphism, it depends on context.  I can't think of any situations at this moment, but I can imagine there are situations where you might care about different group structures which can be given to the total space of principal bundle, which are compatible with the multiplication on the fiber.  With regards to deformation, I'm not really sure what you're asking.